# TFS2013 new build definition error: The type or namespace name 'TestClassAttribute' could not be found

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2013

I created a new build definition on a new installation of TFS 2013 Update 3. I'm using the TfvcTemplate.12.xaml build process template. The tests in the solution use MSTest but won't compile. Here are some of the errors:

The type or namespace name 'TestClassAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
The type or namespace name 'TestClass' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
The type or namespace name 'TestMethodAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
The type or namespace name 'TestMethod' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio needs to be installed on the build server.